# SPFX - Client side solutions cannot be used in this location

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I am facing below issue while adding SPFx package file in App Catalog:

> Client side solutions cannot be used in this location.

**Update**:

I am adding package file in "Apps for Testing" library. "Apps for SharePoint" is not visible in Developer site for me.

Comment: Where are you adding your package file? Are you adding it in "Apps for SharePoint" library?

Comment: no, i am adding in "Apps for Testing" library. "Apps for SharePoint" is not visible in Developer site for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the the SPFx Package file in Global **App Catalog** and not on the Developer site.

You can follow the below article for step by step guide on How to deploy your SPFx solution in App Catalog.

[Deploy the HelloWorld package to app catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page#deploy-the-helloworld-package-to-app-catalog).

> **Note**:
>   If you do not have an app catalog, a SharePoint Online Admin can create one by following the instructions in this guide: [Use the App Catalog to make custom business apps available for your SharePoint Online environment](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-app-catalog-to-make-custom-business-apps-available-for-your-sharepoint-online-environment-0b6ab336-8b83-423f-a06b-bcc52861cba0).

Similar issue is asked on GitHub, you can refer it for more clarification:

[Deployment to Developer Site is not possible: Client Side Solutions cannot be used in this location](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/537).

**Reference**:

For more information on SharePoint Framework, How to setup App catalog and Developer site in Office 365 tenant a demo webpart creation, please follow articles:

[Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

Comment: Thanks for the information, But in Github link it is mentioned that  "The site collection app catalogs are live and available on all tenants" from michel-weber.

Comment: Yes, In that case you need to create a site collection level app catalog. follow the article: [Use the site collection app catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog).